# Firestore: how to make query where field is null

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

In my collection I have several documents where the "token" field is null.

`query := client.Collection("records").Where("token", "==", nil)`

In Go, the query above returns zero documents.

What is the correct query to fetch all documents where the "token" field is null or missing?

Comment: You should test against null (without quotation marks) if they are actually null in the database, not nil, as in .where("foo", "==", null);

Comment: I'm not too familiar with go, but I would expect this to work, as it does similarly in other languages.  There might be a bug in the client library.  Please feel free to file a bug.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, I just filed a bug report

Comment: Can you actually show a screenshot with a document where the field is `null`? I want to make sure the field is present-but-null, and not missing altogether.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, how can you fetch with a query both missing and present-but-null ? Or in case they are two different queries, can you please provide both?

Comment: Firestore doesn't support 'isNotEqual' operator so you can't check for null value directly, but there is a workaround [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481812/4218640).

Comment: @ElectroBuddha that workaround is to detect "not null", by operating on a String domain. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem of detecting "null"

Comment: @DanieleB In that case check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813032/4218640). I'm not sure for Go language, but in Swift it also doesn't work when using `nil` value in 'where' statement, but it works if you instead use instance of null object `NSNull()`. Could you check if there is an equivalent representation of null object in Go lang?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there a NSNull() equivalent for Go?

Answer (score 1):

Currently a bug in the Go client. Track at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/922.