# Firestore: How to query for non-existing (undefined) fields?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

With firestore, how do I write a query to find documents that have an `undefined` field?

For example, here's a firestore collection with two documents:

```
{
  users: { // <- the collection
    a: { // <- the document
      active: true,
      profile: {
        first_name: 'Homer',
        last_name: 'Simpson',
      }
    },
    b:
      active: true
    }
  }
}
```

(Here's screenshots from the firestore console): 
[Document 'a'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC0cd.png)
, [Document 'b'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9EDl.png)

Given the above firestore data, I want to do something like this:
`firestore().collection('users').where('profile', '==', undefined)` (which is not a valid query for firestore)

How can I write a query to retrieve all documents (`users`) where a certain field (`profile`) does NOT exist?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to query for documents based on a missing field. Typically you'll want to include a marker value for that field in each document, such as `null`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806860/how-to-query-cloud-firestore-for-non-existing-keys-of-documents

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping I wouldn't have to include a marker value.  Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen!

Comment: why google cannot do .where('profile', '==', undefined) . sooo sad...

Comment: I guess because a missing fields means a missing index...

Comment: This would have been nice to have for implicit data migration...

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen And if I'll already have thousands of documents. How to add the marker to the ones that don't have the marker. How to query those to add the marker?

Comment: @InfoStatus AFAIK, you have to manually resave the entire Collection :(

Comment: No, you can write a little function that iterates over your collection, checks for the marker, and adds it if the marker is not set. A developer does not have to do anything manually ;-)

Comment: @ValentinSeehausen how?