# How to set where clause for when given field name is undefined?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to set WHERE clause for when the value for the given field name is undefined? I want to get the list of users where they're not an admin, which is marked by undefined value of `user.admin`. I tried this but didn't work. Snapshot is empty.

```
CollectionReference cr = await Firestore.instance.collection('user');
QuerySnapshot qs = await cr.where('admin', isEqualTo : null).get();
print(qs.size);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not store "undefined" values.  The valid values for fields are listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).  Since undefined isn't a valid value, you can't query for it.

If you are asking if Firestore can query for documents where a specific field is missing entirely, that's also not possible.  See:

- [How to query Cloud Firestore for non-existing keys of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806860/how-to-query-cloud-firestore-for-non-existing-keys-of-documents)
- [Firestore select where a field is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431050/firestore-select-where-a-field-is-not-present)

If you want to find a document in a query, you'll have to put some specific, valid, value there and use that in your query.  Often, null is used as a marker for missing data.