# Querying null field in FireStore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that looks for a `gameCreatedAt` that is equal to `null`.  However, even though there are no `null` values in the collection..it still returns data o.O

Here is what the query looks like:

```
const query = firestore().collection('matches')
  query.where('gameStartedAt', '==', null)
  query.where(`lobby.${uid}`, '>', 0)
  query.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  query.limit(1)
```

Here is what the data looks like:
[image]

Not sure why the `query.where('gameStartedAt', '==', null)` criteria seems to get dropped silently? Was hoping someone could explain why the behavior is this way?  It seemed to work in other programming languages with a `NSNULL()` like in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813032/845248) but in JavaScript `null` seems to just get *ignored*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `query` method is returning new query object, not changing the object on which it was called ([reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#where)).

You can do something like that (just remove `query`) in every line:

```
const query = firestore().collection('matches')
  .where('gameStartedAt', '==', null)
  .where(`lobby.${uid}`, '>', 0)
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  .limit(1)
```

This should work fine.